# Export title and contents of text files into separate Excel columns?

Tags: excel, text, automation, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

I have a directory with 1200+ .txt files: e.g., Text0001.txt, Text0002.txt, Text0003.txt...

My goal is to generate a spreadsheet with two columns. In Column A there will be the titles of the text files. In Column B there will be the contents of the respective text files, line breaks and all.

Thus, A1 will read Text0001.txt, and B1 will contain all the contents of Text0001.txt.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  [What have you tried so far?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Glad to hear it's workable. Here was my thought process: I've thought about copying and pasting from Finder the titles organized alphabetically into Column A. Then, it became a question of bringing the contents of those files into Column B organized the same way. I got stuck there. That they're Arabic may or may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the information from these three links you should be able to put something together that will do this by putting all the files in one directory.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

http://software-solutions-online.com/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php